# How to click a plain button on a webpage using VBScript?

Tags: vbscript

I have a button on an website like this

```
<button>
Like
</button>
```

Does anyone know how to find and click this button using VBScript?
Since he have no ID or other things I don't know how to find the button.

Comment: Added a little bit of clarification and changed the title, otherwise the question looks fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems that I am answering my own questions. The more you search, the fastest you learn.

```
Set Butlike = IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("button")
if btn.textContent= "Like" then
    btn.Click()
End if
```